How to show object assignment in a collaboration diagram?
I wonder how to show object assignment in the collaboration diagram I made with this given code, in particular in aNode = path.getLastPathComponent().
/* @author Scott Violet */ 
public class SampleTreeModel extends DefaultTreeModel {
 
    public SampleTreeModel(TreeNode newRoot) { super(newRoot); } 
    public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode aNode =
           (DefaultMutableTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent(); 
        SampleData sampleData = (SampleData)aNode.getUserObject(); 
        sampleData.setString((String)newValue); 
        if (this.isColorGreen) sampleData.setColor(Color.green); 
        else sampleData.setColor(Color.black); 
        nodeChanged(aNode); 
    } 
}

I tried showing the assignment like in the code, but not sure if that is the correct way, maybe the relationships with the objects make this implicit. Hope you can help me. Thanks!


Probably a SD would be a better choice here. SD are on a more tech level while CDs focus more on the business aspect.

@qwerty_so Maybe, I was given this as an assignment with also his sequence diagram which was the easiest one for me to do and understand.

I think, this is the correct way. The assignment target is shown in front of the equals sign. If you wanted to specify the returned value, it would be shown after a colon behind the label of the reply message.
However, I have some remarks on the diagram:

The names of the lifelines (the boxes) should not be underlined.
Messages 2 and 3 use a dot notation to denote the target. This is not allowed and anyway superfluous, since the messages are visually connected to the target.
The assignment is part of the reply message. This would be shown with a dashed arrow. There should be reply messages for all assignments additionally to the request messages. This is the official rule. However, for simple query-operations I think it is ok to show it like you do.
I think your message 1 shows a list of parameters without specified arguments. Then they should be omitted. If you still want to show them, they must be shown appended with "=-". This means the interaction doesn't depend on the concrete value given here.
Your custom stereotypes «local» and «parameter» are assigned to messages. I think they apply to the lifelines, or not?


What about those stray arrows (with the stereo labels)? Never seen it that way.

@qwerty_so the straight arrows are supposed to show the direction of each message (the line between objects is a link and not the message itself.  The stereotypes local, parameter (and global and association...) were in fact adornments of the links.  They were defined in the UML 1.4 specs as far as I remember and explained how the two objects new about each other.  I suppose the modeller translated them into custom stereotypes. However, they should be for the link and not the message imho.

@Axel How do you differentiate the reply messages in a communication diagram?  Is the little arrow on top of the link supposed to be dashed ?  Table 17.4. seems to suggest that the arrow is meant to show the direction in a communication diagram)

Thanks for the remarks, they're very helpful. What do you mean by lifelines? Because the boxes are the objects. Anyway, that's the notation my teacher uses.
Yes, stereotypes should be close to the object, my mistake.
Do you mind showing an example for the assignment with the dashed arrow or the reply messages? I can't find anything like that on internet. That would help me a lot.

@qwerty_so  I knew I had a question on this topic with a couple of relevant quotes:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/69872921/3723423 : in UML 1.4 they were indeed stereotypes.

@Christophe I happen to know only the notation on p. 720 (the triangle along a UMLEdge). Do you have a ref. for the above notation? Also the stereotypes are not to be found in the specs.

@qwerty_so indeed, the stereotypes are no longer in the standard, as Axel confirmed in the answer to the linked question.  The arrow notation with the direction is explained in table 17.4 p.600 with a practical example page 601.  However the description is weak and it is not clear when the table refers to the interaction message notation, if it is for the message name & parameters, or if it also applies to the little arrow (e.g. dashed for return message)...

The boxes are Lifelines, even though no line is shown. The line would be visible in a sequence diagram. Both diagrams have the same metamodel. Lifelines represent attributes or parameters. In UML 1 their name was underlined, but this has been changed by UML 2. The reason is that the underline is reserved for InstanceSpecifications and attributes and parameters are not related to them.

The stereotypes «local» and «parameter» have been defined in UML 1 for Association Ends. Therefore, they are not adornments of the links, but of attributes and parameters. And these are the very elements represented by the lifelines. So, the stereotypes should be shown above the names in the boxes.

The specification doesn't show the different arrows in a communication diagram. However, since they have the same metamodel as a sequence diagram, I think the arrows should be the same. At least, that is how a leading modeling tool is handling it. So, a reply message would be shown with a dashed open arrow.
The specification has an example in Figures 17.26 where two messages share a single arrow. The rules for this are not given. Maybe, it is up to the modeler.
